# On diverged GIT branches

Tags: git

I have several questions on the following sequence of events.

There are 2 developers working on this code .. First and foremost, **what causes branches to diverge on a first place?**

```
11:05:08 ~/myApp $ git status
# On branch Dev
# Your branch and 'origin/Dev' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 3 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
11:10:39 ~/myApp $ git push origin Dev:Dev
To ssh://git@mygitserver/myApp-web.git
 ! [rejected]        Dev -> Dev (non-fast-forward)

error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@mygitserver/myApp-web.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

As Git suggested, i tried to do a pull from `remote/Dev` to local `Dev`, only to see:

```
11:10:51 ~/myApp $ git pull origin Dev:Dev
From ssh://mygitserver/myApp-web
 ! [rejected]        Dev        -> Dev  (non-fast-forward)
```

Git pull worked however. **Why did git pull worked and git pull origin Dev:Dev failed?**

```
11:13:05 ~/myApp $ git pull
Merge made by recursive.
 WebContent/BL/a.jsp               |   14 +++++-------
 WebContent/RJ/b.jsp               |    3 +-
 .../RJ/c.jsp                      |   22 ++++++++++----------
 WebContent/RJ/d.jsp               |   14 ++++++------
 WebContent/TM/e.jsp               |   12 ++++------
 5 files changed, 31 insertions(+), 34 deletions(-)
```

Subsequent `git status` and `git push origin Dev:Dev` worked without adventures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches diverge, when changes happened on the remote AND on your local repositories, think of it as implicit branches: two (or more) commits with the same parent commit. Someone pushed new commits to the repository, while you have committed locally without synchronizing (merge or rebase)

As for `git pull origin Dev:Dev` not working:

`git pull`s [manpage](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-pull.html) describes its usage as:

> ```
> git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
> ```

the refspec part tells git which (remote) refs it should merge into local refs. As such, it only allows fast-forward updates, to prevent you from losing history.

You probably meant to update your remote tracking branch, and not your local one:

```
git pull origin dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev
```

A short-cut notation for your use case exists though:

```
git pull origin dev:
```

`git pull` without arguments will update all tracking branches for the configured remote (usually `origin`) and merges the first refspec into the current branch.

Comment: For the OP: changes happening in the remote *and* local repository really means that someone else made a change and pushed it to the remote, so think of it as divergent development done by you and at least one other developer.

Answer (score 1):

To visualize the divergence, you just had to compare `git log Dev` on both machines.

Comment: Or easier, since you can have all commits on a single machine: `git fetch origin; git log --oneline --graph --decorate Dev...origin/Dev`